# What is the importance of collections framework in java for the programming of android and how to benefit from it

Tags: java, android, xml

How to use true data structure in android programming I need good learning resources and examples of applying data structure in certain functions

Comment: "I need good learning resources" . Just search it on web . Read the Oracle doc .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collections framework was designed to meet several goals, such as −

1. The framework had to be high-performance. The implementations for the fundamental collections (dynamic arrays, linked lists, trees, and hashtables) were to be highly efficient.
2. The framework had to allow different types of collections to work in a similar manner and with a high degree of interoperability.
3. The framework had to extend and/or adapt a collection easily.

A collections framework is a unified architecture for representing and manipulating collections. All collections frameworks contain the following −

Interfaces − These are abstract data types that represent collections. Interfaces allow collections to be manipulated independently of the details of their representation. In object-oriented languages, interfaces generally form a hierarchy.

Implementations, i.e., Classes − These are the concrete implementations of the collection interfaces. In essence, they are reusable data structures.

Algorithms − These are the methods that perform useful computations, such as searching and sorting, on objects that implement collection interfaces. The algorithms are said to be polymorphic: that is, the same method can be used on many different implementations of the appropriate collection interface.

For More Details you can find documents on [ORACLE's Collection Documents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: I need examples of data structure uses to Deepened in my understanding thanks